# Formatting glossary and bibliography's headers

Tags: biblatex, sectioning, glossaries

In the example below, mismatch between OT1H glo and bib's headers, and OTOH the way they appear in the toc: chapter and section, respectively. I would like to change the former to section. Also, there are blank pages on p. 2,4,6, and 8: why?

```
\documentclass[onside,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{expl3}
%\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  in = {dans},
}

\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossary*{cont}{Contact}
\newglossaryentry{dupont}
{
  type=cont,
  name={Dupont, Michel},
  description={}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{lefoo
  ,author =       {Dupond, Marie}
  ,title =        "TITRE"
  ,journal =      "LE JOUR"
  ,year =         "AAAA"
  ,language={french}
  ,hyphenation={french}
}

@article{lebar
  ,author =       {\gls{dupont}}
  ,title =        "TITRE"
  ,journal =      "LE JOUR"
  ,year =         "AAAA"
  ,language={french}
  ,hyphenation={french}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Foo} 
\chapter{bar}
\section{qux}


Erreur dans la référece de \gls{dupont}\autocite{lebar}.

Par d'erreur dans celle-ci: \textcite{lefoo}.


\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\label{index}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Contacts}
\label{glo}
\printnoidxglossary[type=cont]

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Biblio}
\label{thebib}
%\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Half the answer, i guess: `\usepackage[section=section]{glossaries}`

Comment: [This](http://web.archive.org/web/20100703051708/http://www.flakery.org/search/show/568) seemed like a straightforward solution, but `LaTeX error: undefined`: `\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection*{References}}`.

Comment: This: `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]`

Comment: Do those comments mean you have found the solution? If so, please type it up in an answer below, so people can also benefit from it. If not, I suggest you update your question with what you found so far and explain how it still isn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two modifications solve the problem. In the preamble, add:

```
\usepackage[section=section]{glossaries}
```

Inside the `document` environment, replace:

```
\printbibliography
```

with:

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
```